# ChartJS doughnut - Multi line label with click event listener

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs, chartjs-2.6.0

I am using `ChartJS` library to render the doughnut chart. I have custom labels to show with the event listener. I tried by using **chartjs-plugin-datalabels** and **chartjs-plugin-labels**, but no luck maybe I am not an expert in CSS.

The final doughnut is should be like:

[image]

Can anyone have any other suggestions to solve this?

Comment: Please show the code you already have. Also explain what role the "event listener" plays in your question. Do you want to display labels permanently or rather tooltips on mouseover event?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/z4vqf9kL/ 
I want to display labels permanently and want to handle the click event on labels.